# How to get only the date part of GMT in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here's my date string:

```
2022-07-20T11:34:39
```

And here's my code to get GMT:

```
new Date('2022-07-20T11:34:39').toGMTString()
// prints this
// Wed, 20 Jul 2022 07:04:39 GMT
```

However, I only need the date part. `Wed, 20 Jul 2022`. I know I can use substring or regex or split etc. to extract it.

Is there any solution to achieve this without those tricks?

Answer (score 3):

First of all [toGMTString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString) is depracated:

> Note: toGMTString() is deprecated and should no longer be used. It remains implemented only for backward compatibility; please use [toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) instead.

You are looking for [toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString):

```js
const res = new Date('2022-07-20T11:34:39').toDateString()
console.log(res)
```

Or more configurable [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```js
const options = {
  weekday: 'short',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric'
};
const res = new Date('2022-07-20T11:34:39').toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#examples)

```js
const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  weekday: 'short'
})

const dateFormatter2 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
  dateStyle: 'full'
})

const cdate = new Date()

console.log(dateFormatter.format(cdate));
console.log(dateFormatter2.format(cdate));
```